# Replacing matrix columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, replace

I created a matrix in R

```
C<-matrix(c(0),nrow=6,ncol=6,byrow = FALSE)
```

Now I would like to replace the first column of the matrix with the value 1, the second and third column with standard normal random variables and the last three columns with the values of an other matrix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a reproducible example and expected output so we can help you. Have a [look at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and revise your question.

Comment: Please read an *Introduction to R*. You might also benefit from reading `help("[")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
C<-matrix(c(0),nrow=6,ncol=6,byrow = FALSE)
other.matrix<-matrix(runif(18), nrow = 6, ncol = 3)

C[,1]<-1
C[,3]<-rnorm(6)
C[,4:6]<-other.matrix
```

To access the rows and columns of matrices (and for that matter, `data.frames`) in R you can use `[]` brackets and i,j notation, where i is the row and j is the column. For example, the 3rd row and 2nd column of your matrix `C` can be addressed with

```
 C[3,2]
 #[1] 0
```

Use `<-` to assign new values to the rows/columns you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

For the first three columns, you can use

```
C<-matrix(c(0),nrow=6,ncol=6,byrow = FALSE)
C[ ,1] <- 1; C[ ,2] <- rnorm(6); C[ ,3] <- rnorm(6)
```

Let's now say your other matrix is called *D* and looks like

```
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
[1,] 0.6527716 0.81793644 0.67138209 0.3175264 0.1067119 0.5907180 0.4619992
[2,] 0.2268516 0.90893913 0.62917211 0.1768426 0.3659889 0.0339911 0.2322981
[3,] 0.9264116 0.81693835 0.59555163 0.6960895 0.1667125 0.6631861 0.9718530
[4,] 0.2613363 0.06515864 0.04971742 0.7277188 0.2580444 0.3718222 0.8028141
[5,] 0.2526979 0.49294947 0.97502566 0.7962410 0.8321882 0.2981480 0.7098733
[6,] 0.4245959 0.95951112 0.45632856 0.8227812 0.3542232 0.2680804 0.7042317
```

Now let's say you want columns 3,4, and 5 in from *D* as the last three columns in *C*, then you can simply just say

```
C[ ,4:6] <- D[ ,3:5]
```

And your result is

```
     [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,]    1 -1.76111875  0.4621061 0.67138209 0.3175264 0.1067119
[2,]    1  0.40036245  0.9054436 0.62917211 0.1768426 0.3659889
[3,]    1 -1.03238266 -0.6705829 0.59555163 0.6960895 0.1667125
[4,]    1 -0.47064774  0.3119684 0.04971742 0.7277188 0.2580444
[5,]    1 -0.01436411 -0.4688032 0.97502566 0.7962410 0.8321882
[6,]    1 -1.18711832  0.8227810 0.45632856 0.8227812 0.3542232
```

Just one thing to note is that this requires your number of rows to be the same between *C* and *D*.